# Is $ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n=0 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
1+S(x)=x\cdot S(x)
$$
Let's we have the equation above
I noticed there are two solutions of that equation in series :

---

Solution 1:
$$
S_1(x)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$
Showing that
$$
1+ (-1-x-x^2-x^3-....)=x(-1-x-x^2-x^3-....)
$$

---

Solution 2:
$$
S_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{-n}
$$

Showing that
$$
1+ (x^{-1}+x^{-2}+x^{-3}+....)=x(x^{-1}+x^{-2}+x^{-3}+...)
$$

---

If $$
S_1(x)=S_2(x)
$$

We get 
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n=0
$$

Second Method to Show:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}
$$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n}=\frac{1}{1-x^{-1}}
$$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n}=\frac{x}{x-1}
$$

$$
-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n=-1+\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{x-1}=-1+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{x}{1-x}
$$

$$
-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n=-1+\frac{1-x}{1-x}=0
$$

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n=0
$$

But If we test with a number put in $x$ 
 $$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n 
$$
goes to $\infty$  not $0$

Where is the problem in my methods to show the sum is $0$?

Note: I know  that the sum is divergence but I asked that question for some people that wonder why.  I need good mathematical answer to show where the problem is.

Can it be similar to the example of  [Ramanujan’s mysterious expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)?
 $$
(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+.....)=-\frac{1}{12}
$$.

Please see also [the article](https://plus.maths.org/content/infinity-or-just-112) that It mentions that the divergence series that is like above can get result as shown in [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) .

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}=\zeta(x) 
$$

and according to article 
 $$
\zeta(-1) = -\frac{1}{12}
$$

Can it be same kind of thing in my result?

Please explain Ramanujan’s mysterious expression and my strange results.

Thanks

Comment: "Where is the problem in my method to show the sum is 0?" That this method is not mathematics, mainly.

Comment: In the usual definition of infinite sums, $\dotsb+x^{-2}+x^{-1}+1+x+x^2+\dotsb$ does not converge, and thus it doesn't equal zero. (Euler once also thought he showed that it summed to $0$, which is considered one of his mistakes — Euler was often sloppy about notions of convergence.) I suppose you could try to come up with alternative definitions of the sum of an infinite series, but it would probably be tricky to get it to work the way you want it to.

Comment: You might want to look at Cesáro summation. From Wikipedia: "In mathematical analysis, Cesàro summation assigns values to some infinite sums that are not convergent in the usual sense, while coinciding with the standard sum if they are convergent." (That is, it "sums" more series than the normal definition can.) Also look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series).

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger "Euler once also thought he showed that it summed to 0, which is considered one of his mistakes" Do you have any evidence that Euler thought the series *converges*? Because he manipulated divergent series *while knowing they're divergent*.

Answer (score 9):

$\sum_{n\geq 1}x^n$ converges to $\frac{x}{1-x}$ for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$, while $\sum_{n\geq 1}x^{-n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{x-1}$ for any $x$ such that $|x|>1$. So it is not possible that both the series converge at the same time.

Comment: I updated my question . Can there be any connection with Ramanujan’s mysterious expression about infinity sum of numbers  with my infinity sum result? . It was strange in the begining before checking the result for extention zeta function

Comment: @Mathlover: that strange identities came from extending the concept of convergence in some way. For instance, $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ for any $\text{Re}(s>1)$, but the analytic continuation of $\zeta$ is defined over a larger set, so with some abuse we may say that $\sum_{n\geq 1} n$ "equals" $\zeta(-1)=-\frac{1}{12}$. In your case, how do you re-define the concept of convergence of a series? If you don't, you are just adding two series that are never simultaneously convergent.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** *The equation*
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^n=0
$$
*is true for all $x$ such that the series converges.*

That theorem is correct.  But your proof is too involved.  Here is mine:

**Proof**.  The series converges for no $x$.  **QED**

Answer (score 1):

The proof is easier:
$$
S(x)=\sum_{-\infty<n<\infty} x^n=x\sum_{-\infty<n<\infty} x^n=xS(x)
$$
Since $x=0$ must obviously be excluded, we get $S(x)=0$ for $x\ne0$ and $x\ne1$.

Does this mean something? No.